# Java Socket Heartbeats

Tags: java, sockets

I am developing a program that uses sockets and I want to send a heartbeat to my clients every second in order to check if they are still connected.

How do I do this efficiently?

```
                    while (true) { // send heartbeats to client
                    try {
                        socketOut.write(0);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("client disconnected");
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

That is my current code, however the while loop messes up all my other clients.  It makes them unable to connect to the game (the server socket).  How do I accomplish heartbeats without affecting the game and other clients?

**Note:**  I've debating using a timer to achieve my 1 second delays, but I do not know if it will work nor if it is efficient for a large game with many clients connected at once.

Comment: You generally want to add a delay between heartbeats rather than continually writing to the socket.

Comment: That's exactly my thinking.  However, I tried doing it with a delay and it still made my other clients unable to connect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure the server needs to poll clients for a heartbeat rather than to have the client send a heartbeat to the server?

Generally speaking, a server will connect to a socket, wait to accept a client connection, and then process client requests on a separate thread.

I think you would be able to accomplish your goal simply by having the client spawn a heartbeat thread that sleeps for the duration of the heartbeat, then wakes up to send a heartbeat ping to the server. The heartbeat thread on the client would live as long as the client does, it would just loop. Either way, your server would need to keep track of all the clients, either to be able to poll for their heartbeat, or with this approach, just keep track of which clients are actively sending heartbeats.

Comment: Agree, this sounds a lot more efficient

Comment: Sounds good to me!  Can you give me an example of a way to listen for heartbeats from the client?  Wouldn't using a timer/loop to listen for client heartbeats still tie up the code and make my other clients unable to connect?  Maybe I'm using loops wrong, I'm just not sure.

Comment: Using a timer and your idea of sending a heartbeat from the client it works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Try java.util.[Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29)

```
Timer t = new Timer();
t.schedule(new TimerTask(){
   @Override
   public void run(){/*...Your task...*/}
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Awesome!  Works perfect!